# How to copy only PDF files last modified today?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have the below code to copy all PDFs from drive `C:` to drive `D:`.

```
@ECHO OFF
COPY "C:\testing\*.pdf" "D:\testing2\*.pdf"
```

I only want to copy the latest PDF.

What do I need to copy only the files with last modification date equal today´s data?

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\testing" "D:\testing2" *.pdf /M /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:1 /W:2 >nul` copies only the files of which archive attribute is set in source directory and removes the archive attribute after copying the file. The archive attribute is automatically set by Windows on file being created new in the directory, renamed in the directory or modified with an application. If that command line is run once per day, there are only copied the files created/modified/renamed today independent on last modification date.

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\testing" "D:\testing2" *.pdf /MAXAGE:1 /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:1 /W:2 >nul` copies only the files of which last modification date is __not__ older than one day (24 hours), i.e. the last modification date is today or yesterday with less than 24 hours time difference to current time or in the future.

Comment: `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\testing\*.pdf" /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul') do copy /Y "C:\testing\%%I" "D:\testing2\" & goto CopyDone` and next line `:CopyDone` copies just the __newest__ PDF file in `C:\testing` to `D:\testing2` independent on which last modification date it has. `goto CopyDone` can be replaced by `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` if the batch file does not contain other lines below. A batch file is not needed at all if the file copying is done with a scheduled task and the batch file does not contain any other command line then one of the three posted command lines.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I think it works. So if I run this once a day, it will only copied Created/Modified/Rename on today ONLY. Also, this process will not delete any C drive PDFs(the Source) correct?

Comment: There is nothing deleted in source directory by __ROBOCOPY__ or the __FOR__ loop processing the list of file names output by __DIR__ and running the command __COPY__ for the newest file. The first __ROBOCOPY__ command line just removes the archive file attribute of each copied file in source directory.

Comment: For what it's worth, you could also accomplish this with the forfiles command: [forfiles](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

Comment: @Qwerty Yes, it __could__ be done also with `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe`, but it __should not__ be done with this executable because it would be horrible inefficient and slow in comparison to doing that with the solutions provided by me.